# Why is my redux subscription not receiving data from the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

A dispatch is made to the redux store.

```
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("errorX", error.response.data);
  dispatch({
    type: ReducerType.STORE_ERROR_MESSAGE,
    payload: error.response.data,
  });
});
```

The data arrives at the store:

```
case ReducerType.STORE_ERROR_MESSAGE:
  console.log('type', type)
  console.log('payload ', payload )
  return {
    ...state,
    error: payload,
    info: "",
    title: "ERROR",
  };
```

Log statements from the store:

```
type STORE_ERROR_MESSAGE
payload  **** ERROR TESTING ****
```

The store is registered with redux as shown:

```
export default combineReducers({
 messageStore:MessageReducers
})
```

The Message component subscribes to the messageStore:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  messageStore: state.messageStore,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Message);
```

The messageStore is destructured and logged in the Message component as follow:

```
const Message = ({error, info, title}) => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(error || info);

    console.log('message', message)
    console.log('error', error)
    console.log('info', info)
    console.log('title', title)

    return (...)
```

}

But it doesn't show the data that arrived at the store:

```
message undefined
error undefined
info undefined
title undefined
```

Comment: You are destructuring from the `props` object and not from the `messageStore` prop, also you can just use `useSelector` which will simplify the code

Comment: Thank you, Asaf.